# plus minus sign inside the gt() function when rendering to PDF

Tags: html, pdf, latex, special-characters, quarto

```
`reliabilitet2 |> gt() |> fmt_number(decimals = 2) |> cols_merge(columns = c(m, s), 
         pattern = "{1} `&plusmn;` {2}")`
```

This table render well when rendering from quarto to html. But when trying to render to pdf I get an error.
The problem is the plus minus sign inside the     `cols_merge()`     function. Any idea how to make it work to render to pdf with +/- sign?

I have tried changing    `&plusmn;`    with     `$//pm$`    but then I dont get a plus minus sign at all when doing the code. And it just render as this    `$//pm$`    .

Comment: I supose you have to use the hexadecimal utf-8 value of this character.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that when you use `\u00B1` it gets correctly converted by quarto.

Comment: it works for me as well. Thanks a lot!